# Cleaner react code when using loops and map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code working with react, and its just getting very cluttered, so I was wondering if there is a way to make this code and others that are quite similar to look cleaner.

```
render() {
    let result = null;
    var obj = this.state.welcome;
    let test = null;

    if (this.state.isReal) {
      test = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value], index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            Word: "{key}" repeats: {value} times
          </li>
        );
      });
      result = (
        <Aux>
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <ul>{test}</ul>
        </Aux>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Aux>
        <div className="bframe">
          <div className="form" />
          {result}
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </Aux>
    );
  }
```

I was wondering if its possible to move everything before 'return' statement, preferable in a separate file. I tried making a functional component and passing props but im unable to do loops there. Any tips?

Comment: You should avoid using `index` as a key. In your case use `key` instead. See: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce your code to the following :

```
render() {
    const { welcome, isReal } = this.state

    return (
        <Aux>
            <div className="bframe">
                <div className="form" />
                {isReal && 
                    <Aux>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <ul>
                            {Object.entries(welcome).map(([key, value]) => 
                                <li key={key}>
                                    Word: "{key}" repeats: {value} times
                                </li>
                            )}
                        </ul>
                    </Aux>
                }
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </Aux>
    );
}
```

Do not use `var`, by default use `const` and if you want to modify your variable, use `let`.

You can choose to render an element or not by using the inline `if` : `&&`.

Your function is also unnecessary as it can be replaced by inline JS.

Your `map` can also be reduce from : `x.map(a => { return <div/> }` to `x.map(a => <div/>`.

You can also use the `key` of each item as the React `key` since they all have to be unique anyway in your object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following

```js
const Result = ({real, welcome}) => {
  if (!real) return null;
  
  const words = Object.entries(welcome).map(([key, value], index) => <li key={index}>
            Word: "{key}" repeats: {value} times
          </li>
        );
      
  return (
    <Aux>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <ul>{words}</ul>
    </Aux>
  );
}

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
 // ...
  render() {
    const {isReal, welcome} = this.state;

    return (
      <Aux>
        <div className="bframe">
          <div className="form" />
          <Result real={isReal} welcome={welcome}/>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}
```